# Same code block accessed by different callbacks at the same time

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have one scenario, where one function(block of code) is accessed by n different callback functions. If at the same time, more than one callback calls the function, I have to put a mutex in the function such that only one callback can access that at a time and the other callback has to wait till the first one in in the critical section. 
Is this correct design ? Are there any alternative designs ? Is there any way to not make the second callback wait while the first callback is getting processed?

Comment: Such function is called re-entrant function and will execute fine if it uses all local variables or instance variables. You need to synchronize the function or parts of it that use shared/global variables

Answer (score 1):

Depends on that function.

Does it modify shared memory ?
Does it use other functions that exhibits race conditions ?

If the answer is yes then you must apply locking and synchronize the processes. 
Applying the lock from the start till the end of that function will make little sense. Only apply the lock before and after critical section (i.e. code piece where the shared data is updated (written to).